# using Switch-case statement to pull random playing card rank and suit to show user

Tags: c++

I'm to set up Enumeration outside the main function and use a void PlayingCard() to pull the enum rank and suit to display a rank and suit to the user. But I am having a difficult time writing the right code to make it work how I want it to work. I am fairly new to C++. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

I've set up both enum rank() and enum suit() with it's card number and suit in it already. 
I've then set up a switch-case statement in a void PrintCard() function as instructed to do so by our professor. I am trying to pull it into the main() function but it just won't do anything.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

enum Rank // ace high
{
    TWO = 2, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE
};

enum Suit
{
    SPADE, DIAMOND, CLUB, HEART
};

struct Card
{
    Rank rank;
    Suit suit;
};

void PrintCard(Card card);


int main()
{
    int num1 = 2;
    cin >> num1;

        PrintCard;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
void PrintCard(Card card)
{
    switch (card.rank)
    {
    case 14: cout << "The" << card.rank << "of" << card.suit << endl;
        break;
    case 13: cout << "The" << card.rank << "of" << card.suit << endl;
        break;
    case 12: cout << "The" << card.rank << "of" << card.suit << endl;
        break;
    case 11: cout << "The" << card.rank << "of" << card.suit << endl;
        break;
    case 10: cout << "The" << card.rank << "of" << card.suit << endl;
        break;
    case 9: cout << "The" << card.rank << "of" << card.suit << endl;
        break;
    case 8: cout << "The" << card.rank << "of" << card.suit << endl;
        break;
    case 7: cout << "The" << card.rank << "of" << card.suit << endl;
        break;
    case 6: cout << "The" << card.rank << "of" << card.suit << endl;
        break;
    case 5: cout << "The" << card.rank << "of" << card.suit << endl;
        break;
    case 4: cout << "The" << card.rank << "of" << card.suit << endl;
        break;
    case 3: cout << "The" << card.rank << "of" << card.suit << endl;
        break;
    case 2: cout << "The" << card.rank << "of" << card.suit << endl;
        break;
    default: 
        cout << "Wrong Input" << endl;
    }   
}
```

I expect it to show a suit and a rank to the user as I enter a number but the input is just blank and I cannot pull anything from the PrintCard function to use.

Comment: Pay attention to your compiler warnings, you should see something like `expression result unused`, `statement has no effect` or `function call missing argument list` depending on your compiler

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling your `PrintCard` function properly:

```
int main()
{
    int num1 = 2;
    cin >> num1;

    Card card;
    card.rank = Rank::TWO;
    card.suit = Suit::SPADE;
    PrintCard(card);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Create a card object, assign it with rank and suit and then call with this object your `PrintCard` function.

Additional add spaces in your cout:

```
cout << "The " << card.rank << " of " << card.suit << endl;
```

You don't need your switch.case because every case does the same:

```
void PrintCard(Card card)
{
    cout << "The " << card.rank << " of " << card.suit << endl;
}
```

If you wanted to print the enum names, then you would have to use a switch-case.
Example:

```
std::string str;
switch (card.rank):
   case Rank::TWO:
       str = "two";
       break;
       ...

cout << str;
```

Comment: Thank you, 

         I use the code that you gave and was able to show it's results but it would only show the value of the given enum not the actual name. Our professor wants us to use the enum through pulling it into the main function and showing 
"The Two of Hearts", "The King of Diamond", etc. 

Is there a way to convert enum into string as it is cout into string type?

Comment: No, not that i know. You have to convert every case with your switch case like in the example above

Comment: Okay thank you. Do you know how to compare two cards together and let it tell the user which card is the higher value card? we also have to code 

Card HighCard (Card card1, Card card2)

to compare both cards

Answer (score 0):

Okay thank you I'll try to rename the function card.

I've made some comparison but I don't really know how to make it compare itself with the other card and to determine which card is the highest.

```
Card HighCard(Card card1, Card card2)
{
    int rank1;
    int rank2;
    switch (card1.rank)
    {
    case two: rank1 = 2;
        cout << "The first card is a Two of ";
        break;
    case three: rank1 = 3;
        cout << "The first card is a Three of ";
        break;
    case four: rank1 = 4;
        cout << "The first card is a Four of ";
        break;
    case five: rank1 = 5;
        cout << "The first card is a Five of ";
        break;
    case six: rank1 = 6;
        cout << "The first card is a Six of ";
        break;
    case seven: rank1 = 7;
        cout << "The first card is a Seven of ";
        break;
    case eight: rank1 = 8;
        cout << "The first card is a Eight of ";
        break;
    case nine: rank1 = 9;
        cout << "The first card is a Nine of ";
        break;
    case ten: rank1 = 10;
        cout << "The first card is a Ten of ";
        break;
    case jack: rank1 = 11;
        cout << "The first card is a Jack of ";
        break;
    case queen: rank1 = 12;
        cout << "The first card is a Queen of ";
        break;
    case king: rank1 = 13;
        cout << "The first card is a King of ";
        break;
    case ace: rank1 = 14;
        cout << "The first card is a Ace of ";
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Not a card rank";
    }
    switch (card1.suit)
    {
    case heart: cout << "Heart.\n";
        break;
    case diamond: cout << "Diamond.\n";
        break;
    case club: cout << "Club.\n";
        break;
    case spade: cout << "Spade.\n";
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Not a card rank";
    }


    switch (card2.rank)
    {
    case two: rank2 = 2;
        cout << "The second card is a Two of ";
        break;
    case three: rank2 = 3;
        cout << "The second card is a Three of ";
        break;
    case four: rank2 = 4;
        cout << "The second card is a Four of ";
        break;
    case five: rank2 = 5;
        cout << "The second card is a Five of ";
        break;
    case six: rank2 = 6;
        cout << "The second card is a Six of ";
        break;
    case seven: rank2 = 7;
        cout << "The second card is a Seven of ";
        break;
    case eight: rank2 = 8;
        cout << "The second card is a Eight of ";
        break;
    case nine: rank2 = 9;
        cout << "The second card is a Nine of ";
        break;
    case ten: rank2 = 10;
        cout << "The second card is a Ten of ";
        break;
    case jack: rank2 = 11;
        cout << "The second card is a Jack of ";
        break;
    case queen: rank2 = 12;
        cout << "The second card is a Queen of ";
        break;
    case king: rank2 = 13;
        cout << "The second card is a King of ";
        break;
    case ace: rank2 = 14;
        cout << "The second card is a Ace of ";
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Not a card rank";
    }
    switch (card2.suit)
    {
    case heart: cout << "Heart.\n";
        break;
    case diamond: cout << "Diamond.\n";
        break;
    case club: cout << "Club.\n";
        break;
    case spade: cout << "Spade.\n";
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Not a card rank";
    }

    if (rank1 < rank2)
    {
        cout << "The second card has the higher rank.";
    }
    if (rank2 < rank1)
    {
        cout << "The first card has the higher rank.";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "These cards' ranks are equal.";
    }

    return card1, card2;
}

int main()
{


    Card card;
    card.rank = ace;
    card.suit = spade;

    PrintCard(card);

    Card card1;
    card1.rank = eight;
    card1.suit = heart;
    Card card2;
    card2.rank = six;
    card2.suit = club;

    HighCard(card1, card2);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @BithikaMookherjee, I replaced it but now the Card result = HighCard(card1, card2)  is giving me error. card1 and card2 is undefine which it shouldn't since I'm pulling it from the function HighCard.

Comment: Because I've removed the card declaration in the main() function since i'm telling the user to input the value of a card to pull it from Struct Card to show the user and then the computer will determine whether the two card being pull are greater or less than each other by pulling the function Card HighCard(Card card1, Card card2) to use and determine to the user.

Comment: @BithikaMookherjee I just compiled what everyone suggested into one code, the one's that is working accordingly to what my instructor wanted and turned it in. But I'm sure i'll have to re-do the lab exercise...

Comment: I want to refine the code better so that it will run accordingly to how I expect it to though. Is there a way to create other function and by using those other function by function declaration in the main function to calculate to see which card is the highest card? 

Such as what we discussed about where we called the card to use by inputting the value of the card from the enum function but is it possible to use another function to gather the card we call to use and have that function determine if those two card are bigger than the other or not?